# SQL Alias with Select

Tags: sql, alias

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
Voornaam   Tussenvoegsel   Achternaam
Armin      van             Buuren
```

(just an example name)

What I want to do now is select these 3 columns so I can use them seperately but also as a fullname. I think this should be possible using 'AS' but I just can't figure it out. I have tried something like this:

```
$strSQL     = "Select *, (Voornaam & ' ' & Tussenvoegsel & ' ' & Achternaam)  AS Volnaam FROM VTA";  
$objQuery   = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]"); 
$objResult  = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);

echo $objResult['Volnaam'];
```

But this will output '0' instead of 'Armin van Buuren'. I hope you understand my question and if anyone knows what I am doing wrong it would be great!

And btw, I know I shouldn't be using mysql_ but that isn't the issue atm. (will switch to PDO soon)

Comment: Don't use `mysql_()` functions, because they're deprecated. Instead use the new PDO library functions.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Take a look at the last sentence, read the question before you post such comments next time.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use `concat` to add strings together:

```
concat(Voornaam,
case 
when coalesce(Tusselvoegsel,'') <> '' then ' ' + Tussenvoegsel 
else ''
end,
Achternaam) AS Volnaam
```

Comment: What would my full query look like with this? I get this error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/Mail/test/VTA.php on line 16`

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL string concatenation operator + instead of &

Comment: Replacing the &'s with +'s still outputs '0'.